# Does RegularExpression support "(?R)"?

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Mathematica's `RegularExpression` is [based on Perl's PCRE library](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#274403895), which [supports recursive regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) using `(?R)` (or, equivalently, `(?0)`).

This expression should match all palindromes:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["(.)((?R)|.?)\\1"]]
```

However, it only finds three-letter palindromes.  (It also matches two-letter palindromes, but there are none in the dictionary.)  There's no error, so Mathematica seems to parse but discard the recursive pattern, leaving just `(.).?\\1`.

Does Mathematica disable some features of PCRE?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This response is really just an extended comment in support of the hypothesis that *Mathematica* is anchoring the pattern to the beginning and end of the string.  In addition to the compelling behavioural observations reported in @2012rcampion's response, I submit the evidence of the following expressions:

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Trace[StringMatchQ["a", a_], TraceInternal->True]
```

[image: trace output]

We can see near the beginning of the trace output that the pattern is being anchored to `StartOfString` and `EndOfString`:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[StartOfString ~~ a_ ~~ EndOfString, None, 2]
```

Further down, we see the regular expression `(?ms)\A(.)\z`, again anchored to the string boundaries.

Unfortunately, this particular spelunking technique will not reveal the inner workings of `RegularExpression[...]` conversion.  But it stands to reason that such conversions will follow the apparent anchoring policy exhibited in the simpler example.

We can see the *lack* of anchoring in contexts that would demand its absence, e.g.

```
StringCases["123AABCBAA123", RegularExpression["(.)((?R)|.?)\\1"]]
(* {"AABCBAA"} *)

StringReplace["123AABCBAA123", RegularExpression["(.)((?R)|.?)\\1"] -> "!!!"]
(* "123!!!123" *)
```

But even that last example is fragile.  Consider what happens when we attempt to name the matched expression:

```
StringReplace["123AABCBAA123", r:RegularExpression["(.)((?R)|.?)\\1"] :> "("~~r~~")"]
(* "123AABCBAA123" *)
```

*Mathematica* has quietly introduced a capturing group that precedes ours, so `\\1` is no longer referring to what we expect.  This is readily confirmed by changing `\\1` to `\\2`:

```
StringReplace["123AABCBAA123", r:RegularExpression["(.)((?R)|.?)\\2"] :> "("~~r~~")"]
(* "123(AABCBAA)123" *)
```

So, there is a moral to this story: assume that *Mathematica* is going to add elements to the regular expression.  Thus, `(?R)` is not fully reliable since it matches the whole pattern, and the "whole pattern" is out of our control.  We must content ourselves with using explicitly referenced subpatterns (e.g. `(?1)`, `(?2)` etc).  And even then, we must be wary of any implicit capturing groups or PCRE callbacks that *Mathematica* might add.

**UPDATE - Named Patterns**

As @2012rcampion points out in a comment, it is probably safest to use named patterns instead of numbered patterns to avoid conflicting with implicit capturing groups.  PCRE in *Mathematica* appears to be configured so that only `(?P)` syntax is supported:

- `(?P<n>...)` defines the pattern named `n` which matches `...`
- `(?P=n)` is a back-reference to the latest match for the pattern named `n`
- `(?P>n)` is a reference to the pattern named `n` itself (e.g. for recursion)

If we adjust the pattern from the question to use named subpatterns, we get this:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["(?P<a>(?P<b>.)((?P>a)|.?)(?P=b))"]]
(*
   {"aha", "aka", "bib", "bob", "boob", "bub", "CFC", "civic", "dad", "deed",
    "deified", "did", "dud", "DVD", "eke", "ere", "eve", "ewe", "eye", "gag",
    "gig", "huh", "kayak", "kook", "level", "ma'am", "madam", "mam", "MGM",
    "minim", "mom", "mum", "nan", "non", "noon", "nun", "oho", "pap", "peep",
    "pep", "pip", "poop", "pop", "pup", "radar", "redder", "refer", "repaper",
    "reviver", "rotor", "sagas", "sees", "seres", "sexes", "shahs", "sis",
    "solos", "SOS", "stats", "stets", "tat", "tenet", "TNT", "toot", "tot",
    "tut", "wow", "WWW"}
*)
```

This pattern:

1. names the entire pattern *a*
2. captures a character and calls it *b*
3. either recurses into the entire pattern *a* or matches 0..1 character
4. matches the character captured as *b*

This dodges the implicit string anchoring, and is relatively robust with respect to implicit captures.

**UPDATE 2 - Expanded backreference syntax in v10.1+**

As [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) notes in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72724/does-regularexpression-support-r/72739?noredirect=1#comment389732_72739), later versions of *Mathematica* support new styles of backreference and subroutine reference.  From version 10.1 onward, we can write our expression in [Python, Perl or Oniguruma styles](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC20):

```
{ "(?P<a>(?P<b>.)((?P>a)|.?)(?P=b))"   (* Python, as above *)
, "(?<a>(?<b>.)((?&a)|.?)(\\k<b>))"    (* Perl *)
, "(?'a'(?'b'.)((?&a)|.?)(\\k'b'))"    (* Perl *)
, "(?<a>(?<b>.)((\\g<a>)|.?)(\\g{b}))" (* Oniguruma *)
, "(?<a>(?<b>.)((\\g'a')|.?)(\\g{b}))" (* Oniguruma *)
} // Map[DictionaryLookup @* RegularExpression] // SameQ

(* True *)
```

Comment: Nice "comment" -- +1.

Comment: Seems the only truly safe way to handle regexes is to use named groups instead of numbered ones.

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, good idea.  I have updated my answer to give an example.  I suppose this post has outgrown its original billing as just an extended comment... :)

Comment: As @Stitch notes in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143419/280) post, "the `(?<n>)`/`(?&n)` syntax works as well as `(?P<n>)`/`(?P>n)`."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It looks like the additional syntax forms were added in v10.1.  I have updated my post.  Thanks.

Comment: From where you learned all these styles and their names? Also, was this a change on the *Mathematica* side or on the PCRE side?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I refer to the PCRE man pages, particularly the [syntax](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html) page.  I remember trying all the styles when I originally wrote this post and finding that only the Python syntax was supported.  The set of valid styles is controlled by a compile-time switch on the PCRE library.  Perhaps WRI compiled it with a different switch for 10.1, or perhaps the compilation defaults changed with an updated release.of PCRE (e.g. PCRE2).

Answer (score 5):

I realized I should probably double-check that the regular expression was correct... it worked on [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/cE0uM9/1), but I wanted to test it on my computer, just in case.  Running the command:

```
grep -P '(.)((?R)|.?)\1' /usr/share/dict/words
```

resulted in matching every word that contained a palindrome inside it (e.g. `Abbott -> bb`).  Of course, simply adding `^$` to match the beginning and end would't work, since the recursive match would also need to match the beginning and end (which never occurs), so we would end up with something equivalent to `^(.).?\1$` (seem familiar yet?).  Also, it seems like you can't use `-w` with `-P`.

This, however, works fine:

```
grep -P '^((.)((?1)|.?)\2)$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

By changing the recursive part (now `(?1)`) to only recurse on the (new) first capturing group, we avoid trying to re-match the beginning and end (while `\1` has been demoted to `\2`).

Then I went back to Mathematica and tried this:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["((.)((?1)|.?)\\2)"]]
```

and it worked perfectly.  So it seems to me that **Mathematica prepends and appends `^` and `$` to a regular expression used in a string pattern.**

Comment: I believe we can see what *Mathematica* does with the pattern with this: ``StringPattern`PatternConvert[RegularExpression["((.)((?1)|.?)\\2)"]]`` output:  `{"(?ms)(?:((.)((?1)|.?)\\2))", {}, {}, Hold[None]}`.  Does the first part of that agree with what you're observing?

Answer (score 2):

Still looking at it, but (just in case) I think you don't need that pattern to detect palindromes:

```
DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["^(?:(.)(?=.*(\\1(?(2)\\2|))$))*.?\\2?$"]]
(*
{"a", "aha", "aka", "bib", "bob", "boob", "bub", "CFC", "civic", \
"dad", "deed", "deified", "did", "dud", "DVD", "eke", "ere", "eve", \
"ewe", "eye", "gag", "gig", "huh", "I", "kayak", "kook", "level", \
"ma'am", "madam", "mam", "MGM", "minim", "mom", "mum", "nan", "non", \
"noon", "nun", "oho", "pap", "peep", "pep", "pip", "poop", "pop", \
"pup", "radar", "redder", "refer", "repaper", "reviver", "rotor", \
"sagas", "sees", "seres", "sexes", "shahs", "sis", "solos", "SOS", \
"stats", "stets", "tat", "tenet", "TNT", "toot", "tot", "tut", "wow", \
"WWW"}
*)
```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question (can you use `(?R)`?), but quite neat!  Can you explain how this one works?  I'm stuck on the nested reference...

Comment: @2012rcampion Googling for "PCRE palindrome" you'll find a lot of equivalent regexes. Some of them do work in Mathematica and others don't. I guess that depends on the PCRE version

Comment: [Explanation on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3747442), for those who are curious.