# Why does this recursive pattern guard not work?

Tags: pattern-matching, recursion

I have the following list:

```
lst = {
    "str 1,1",
    {"str 1,2,1", "str 1,2,2"},
    {
        (* Inner list 1 *)
        {"str 2,1", {"str 2,2,1"}, {{"str 3,1", {"str 3,2,1", "str 3,2,2"}, {}}}},
        (* Inner list 2 *)
        {"str 4,1", {"str 4,2,1"}, {{"str 5,1", {"str 5,2,1", "str 5,2,2"}, {"str 5,3"}}}},
        (* Inner list 3 *)
        {"str 6,1", {"str 6,2,1", "str 6,2,2"}, {}}
    }
};
```

The list `lst` is a three-element list, and is intended to have the following structure: the first element is a string; the second element is a list of strings, possibly empty; the third element is either the empty list, or a list of strings, or a list whose members have the same recursive structure as `lst`.

I have constructed the following pattern guard for `lst`:

```
ptn = {_String, {___String}, {___String} | (a_ /; MatchQ[a, {ptn..}])};
```

This guard works when the third element of `lst` contains any one of the three inner lists shown.  It also works when the third element of `lst` contains `Inner list 1` and `Inner list 3`, or `Inner list 2` and `Inner list 3`, but not when it contains `Inner list 1` and `Inner list 2`.

Can you please correct the pattern guard?

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85683/193

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I also tried `ptn = {_String, {___String}, a_ /; MatchQ[a, {___String} | {ptn..}]}` but to no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursive patterns are tricky. I suggest you to browse this site for different approaches.

In the current case you have to include patterns to match both `ptn` and lists of `ptn`:

```
ptn = {_String, {___String}, {___String} | 
          (a_ /; MatchQ[a, ptn ..]) | (a_ /; And @@ (MatchQ[#, ptn ..] & /@ a))};

MatchQ[lst, ptn]
(* True *)

MatchQ[{"a", {}, {}}, ptn]
(* True *)

MatchQ[{"a", {"b"}}, ptn]
(* False *)

l = {u, {u, {v, {u, {u, v}}}}} /.
                              u -> Sequence @@ {"a", {"b"}} /. v -> {"a", {"b"}, {"c"}}
(* {"a", {"b"}, {"a", {"b"}, {{"a", {"b"}, {"c"}}, {"a", {"b"}, {"a", {"b"}, 
   {"a", {"b"}, {"c"}}}}}}} *)

MatchQ[l, ptn]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Very interesting.  This has taught me something.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the second time I shall [recommend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87277/121) that you adopt a different method to recursive patterns.  [This method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045/121) has [demonstrable advantages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86899/121) of efficiency, brevity and evaluation control.

The needed code:

```
test[{_String, {___String}, {___String} | _?test | {__?test}}] = True;

_test = False;
```

Borrowing belisarius's examples for testing:

```
lst            // test
{"a", {}, {} } // test
{"a", {"b"}}   // test

l = {u, {u, {v, {u, {u, v}}}}} /. u -> Sequence["a", {"b"}] /. 
   v -> {"a", {"b"}, {"c"}};

l // test
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
>
> False
>
> True
> ```

As explained before converting this predicate function `test` into a pattern is as simple as `_?test`:

```
MatchQ[lst, _?test]  (* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that.  I will keep your recommendation in mind now.