# Count elements between matching opening and closing parentheses?

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

Suppose I have a `List` of the form:

```
lst={"(", "x1", "x2", "(", "(", "x3", ")", "x5", "(", "x6", ")", ")", ")"}
```

For each pair of matching opening and closing parenthesis, I need to count the number of `x`'s inside. More precisely, I need to obtain a list of triplets, `{op, clos, no}`, where `op` and `clos` are the positions of the matching `(` and `)`, and `no` is the number of `x`'s inside. The list of triplets should contain one triplet per matching pair of parenthesis. I am sure there are ways to do this using loops, but I want to see the *Mathematica* way.

For the example `lst` defined above, the **expected result** is:

```
{{1,13,5}, {4,12,3}, {5,7,1}, {9,11,1}}
```

Comment: This is a generalization of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77779/534

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified code from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77788/81), where I only show the code for `match`, and the other (helper) functions should be taken from that post verbatim:

```
ClearAll[match];
match[l_List] := withInfiniteIteration@match[toLL[enumerate@l], ll[], ll[]];

match[ll[{"(", p_}, tail_ll], accum_, res_] := 
   match[tail, ll[{p, 0}, accum], res];

match[ll[{")", pc_}, tail_ll],  ll[{po_, elems_}, ll[{popar_, elemspar_}, rest_]], res_] := 
   match[tail, ll[{popar, elemspar + elems}, rest], ll[{po, pc, elems}, res]];

match[ll[{")", pc_}, tail_ll], ll[{po_, elems_}, ll[]], res_] := 
   match[tail, ll[], ll[{po, pc, elems}, res]];

match[ll[{_, _}, tail_ll], ll[{po_, elems_}, rest_], res_] :=
   match[tail, ll[{po, elems + 1}, rest], res];

match[ll[], ll[], res_ll] := Sort[fromLL[res]];

match[___] := $Failed;
```

What basically happens is that we accumulate the stack when parsing, and record the number of elements parsed into a given block of matched parentheses. When we close the block, we add the inner element count to that of the parent block. An equivalent procedure would've been to first construct a decorated tree with element counts and positions, and then traverse it to pick the positions and element counts, but here we do it on the fly as we parse.So:

```
lst = {"(", "x1", "x2", "(", "(", "x3", ")", "x5", "(", "x6", ")", ")", ")"};

match[lst]

(* {{1, 13, 5}, {4, 12, 3}, {5, 7, 1}, {9, 11, 1}} *)
```

This method should have a linear complexity in the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Reap[
    lst //. 
    {f___, PatternSequence["(", a__?(FreeQ["(" | ")"]), ")"], l___} :> 
       (Sow[{Length[{f}] + 1, Length[{f}] + Length[{a}] + 2, Count[{a}, Except[Null]]}]; 
        {f, Null, a, Null, l}
       );
] // Last // Last // Reverse
```

> {{1, 13, 5}, {4, 12, 3}, {9, 11, 1}, {5, 7, 1}}